# Binary base64encode at CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Is there a way to base64 encode binary data at CasperJS?
I mean something like that:

```
var pdfFile = require('fs').open('some.pdf', 'br');
var pdf = pdfFile.read();
var encoded = _some_func_for_encode(pdf);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use native js method like  btoa() and atob() .

Here is a very basic phantomjs script :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var filedata = fs.read('thefilehere');
var res = btoa(filedata);
console.log(res);
phantom.exit();
```

Base64 encoding/decoding is not so complex and you can easily find js function such as [this one](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, PhantomJS does not support btoa(). In addition, all libraries that I have found, are able to encode only the string, but not binary data.

Comment: PhantomJS does not support btoa() but webpage module supports it. Since phantomJs uses WebKit, it works. See my code

Comment: Phantom now supports it; just tested it in the console. Answer modified.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`casper.base64encode()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#base64encode) to Base64-encode a resource:

```
var base64_file = casper.base64encode('https://example.com/some.pdf');
```